# How do I convert .bash_profile to .zprofile

Tags: bash, zsh

With OSX Catalina they want you to use zsh for the shell and I had a bash profile (that I "borrowed") that I like. But I'm not a shell expert and I don't know how to convert it. Below is the .bash_profile I would like to convert.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

export TERM=xterm-256color
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=Fafacxdxbxegedabagacad

GREEN=$(tput setaf 2);
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3);
RESET=$(tput sgr0);

function get_branch {
 git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\ \(\1\)/'
}

function random_element {
 declare -a array=("$@")
 r=$((RANDOM % ${#array[@]}))
 printf "%s\n" "${array[$r]}"
}

setEmoji () {
 EMOJI="$*"
 PS1="${YELLOW}\w${GREEN}\$(get_branch)${RESET} ${EMOJI}\n$ ";
}

newRandomEmoji () {
  setEmoji "$(random_element      ⛄                 ⚛️        ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍                    ✨ ☄️ ⚡️     ⚗️   ⚪️ )"
}

newRandomEmoji

newRandomEmoji

alias jestify="PS1=\"\n$ \"";
alias cypressify="PS1=\"\n$ \"";

# history size
HISTSIZE=5000
HISTFILESIZE=10000

# PATH ALTERATIONS
## Node
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH:./node_modules/.bin";

# Custom bins
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.bin";

CDPATH=.:$HOME:$HOME/code:$HOME/Desktop

alias ll="ls -la"
alias cls="clear"

alias pj="cd ~/Projects"
```

Namely I can do without the random emoji (it was just fun). But I want the color prompt. I liked having the branch listed in the prompt so I always knew if I was in a git repo and what branch was currently checked out.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried to source your existing file with `source ~/.bash_profile`? _zsh_ is a great deal compatible with _bash_ syntax. As you use command substitution in your prompt, you have to set an option in zsh (`setopt PROMPT_SUBST`), too.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest copying the contents of that existing '.bash_profile' into your new '~/.zshrc' file. The variables, functions, and aliases should work as is.
For the prompt you desire, Zsh supports a rich prompt. I would recommend the new Powerlevel10k prompt; it is very fast, fully customizable, and informative. Installation help is at https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k. 
Before settling on your prompt, you may want to investigate a plugin framework for your zsh, each with its own manner of adding custom prompts. Oh-my-zsh and Prezto are two common and helpful managers, though there are many, and you could roll your own or go without if you choose. Prezto (https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) can get you moving quickly,  though I have lately switched over to oh-my-zsh (https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), which is pretty easy and clean, as well.

Comment: copy contents or just rename the file? lol